# Convert a list of numpy vectors to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays. My list contains 5000 numpy arrays and each one has the size (1x1000). I want to construct a numpy array of size 5000x1000. I am trying to do something like:

```
db_array = np.asarray(db_list) # my db_list has 5000 samples of 1x1000 size
```

The result was a matrix of size (5000, 1, 1000). How can I construct a matrix with size (5000, 1000)?

Comment: You can use `.reshape(5000,1000`)

Comment: Just reshape the array

Comment: I tried reshape and the reuslt was the same. 
db_array = db_array.reshape(5000, 1000). I got (5000, 1, 1000) when I tried db_array.shape

Comment: `vstack` is another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MCVE would help here, but if I understand correctly, just use the `numpy.array` constructor.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arraylist = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1,2,3])]
>>> arraylist
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3])]
>>> np.array(arraylist)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: As a matter of fact in order to work I convert the list using the the np.array() but then i needed also to reshape. With np.asarray() it did not work.

Comment: @konstantin then your list does have a different format than the one in my demo which you did not tell us about.

Answer (score 2):

So, just initialize the list as a simple numpy array

```
import numpy as np

list = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1,2,3])]
new_array = np.array(list)
print (new_array)
print (new_array.shape)
```